# checking parameter passed is string and integer

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am new to powershell scripting. I am supposed to check to see if the first parameter passed is a string and second parameter is an int.

```
function positions { 
    param (
    [string] $inputstring,
    [int] $num )
     } 

$inputstring=read-host "Enter your name" 
if ( !$inputstring -eq "" ) {
    Write-Output "The first recieved parameter is: " $inputstring "and its type is a string"}
else { Write-Output "The first received parameter is:" $inputstring "and its type is not a string" }

$num=read-Host "Enter a number"
if ( $num -eq int ) {
    Write-Output "This second parameter is" $num "and its type is a integer"}
else { Write-Output "This second parameter is" $num "and its type is not a integer"}
```

I believe the if statement for the string is wrong because it give me right input only if i negate it with '!'

Also, for the int, if statement it is not reading 'int' after -eq.

I am extremely new to this so need help.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, when you take input from screen using `read-host` the input will be read and stored as a string, irrespective of what you enter. You can confirm this by running the following command and entering a number:

`($checkInt = read-host).GetType().Name`

This will output string, no matter what you enter. The equivalent would be to define the input variable like this:

`$checkInt = "10"`

```
$StringVariable = "This is a string"
$IntVariable = 10
$StringIntVariable = "10"

## Print out variable types
"String variable is type " + $StringVariable.GetType().Name
"Int variable is type " + $IntVariable.GetType().Name
"StringInt variable is type " + $StringIntVariable.GetType().Name
```

Which again, if you check the type of that variable will return **string**.

What you need to do is **cast to an int and check if the value is null** or check if the value is numeric:

```
## Checking if user input is alphanumeric
$stringIntVariable = Read-Host "Enter a number"
if (($stringIntVariable -as [int]) -ne $null) {
    "StringIntVariable is numeric"
}
else {
    "StringIntVariable is not numeric"
}
```

With regards to your code, the below will work how you want it to:

```
$inputstring = read-host "Enter your name" 

if (($inputstring -as [int]) -eq $null) { ## Check if not castable to int
    Write-Output "The first recieved parameter is: " $inputstring "and its type is a string"
}
else { 
    Write-Output "The first received parameter is:" $inputstring "and its type is not a string" 
}

$num=read-Host "Enter a number"

## Checking if user input is numeric
if (($num -as [int]) -ne $null) {
    Write-Output "This second parameter is" $num "and its type is a integer"
}
else {
    Write-Output "This second parameter is" $num "and its type is not a integer"
}
```

As [@TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) pointed out using `($num -as [int]) -ne $null` is more forgiving than using a regex match.

Comment: You could also cast the second item as an int, and see if it is null. `if (($num -as [int]) -ne $null){ 'Second param is an int' }else{ 'Second param is not an int' }`. This is a little more forgiving, as it ignores some whitespace, but still only returns `$true` if PowerShell can interpret the input as an integer.

Comment: Have edited the answer. For some reason, using that regex returned true if the first characters before the first space were numeric. Your cast method did not.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I understand the part of Read-host always taking in the input as a string. I ran the code and when i enter a integer when read-host asks for a name, it says this is a string, rather than it going to this is not a string. Is this also because it will read input as a string. maybe i will need an else if statement as well

Comment: It becomes a bit more difficult with checking for the string as whatever you enter will be a string. I guess you could change the if statement to be `if (($inputstring -as [int]) -eq $null) {` which is just checking that the input is not castable to type int (See edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetType()`.

When checking for type equality put square brackets around the type (`[string]`):

```
if ( $inputstring.GetType() -eq [string] ) 
{
    # $inputstring is type String
}
else 
{
   ...
}
```

The value coming from `Read-Host` will always be a string, so one option to verify `$num` is an `int` is to cast it to an `int`. However, this will throw an exception if the input is not actually an integer, so instead of `if else` you could use `try catch` block:

```
$num = read-Host "Enter a number"
try {
    # cast to int
    $num = [int]$num
    # $num is type int (Int32)
}
catch
{
    # $num is not an int
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `$InputString -is [string]` & `$Num -is [int]` make more sense?

Comment: It would still return false anyway, he is getting the number input from user so it will return a string. he needs to check if the input is alphanumeric

Comment: @Lee_Dailey `-is` doesn't work on the version of powershell I'm using. @Owain yup, didn't think about that! It'll be a string so would need to cast to `int` first, I guess

Comment: If you use that logic your `If ( $num.GetType() -eq [int])` test fails too.

Comment: @OwainEsau - arg! i missed that entirely ... thank you for the heads-up! [*grin*]

Comment: @haldo - yep, i missed the version AND the string input info. [*blush*] it looks like you need to use regex to test for digits in the "supposed to be a number" item.